# Azure Function Scaling and File Storage

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I currently have a Function App in Azure which uses files to create a network in memory. If the files are not available, they will be copied from an Azure Storage Account (Blob) - taking about 12 seconds. If the files are available it takes a second on the first request.

The issue is that when the app scales out, the newer instances don't have those files and then requires 12 seconds to download the files before they can properly start requests.

Is there a way so that when the function scales, it also copies those files. The files are stored in the temp directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using consumption plan, as your function scales, all your instances are not guaranteed to be on the same VM and therefore it wouldn't be able to share local cache.

The temp directory is only available to the functions running on that same instance. It is not possible to copy the files from the temp directory for the new function instances.  **The best way is by using the durable functions, or other Azure storage (such as blob) to share data between all functions persistently.**

Another way is by using **Pre-warmed Instances**. These are instances warmed as a buffer during scale and activation events, to help in decreasing the cold start time as in your case. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-warmup?tabs=csharp) for more information.

Comment: So when scaling does everything in the home directory get cloned?

Comment: No the home directory do not clone everything when scaling. In your case the pre-warmed instances will be the best choice for removing the initial start time that you mentioned above. Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#pre-warmed-instances) for more information on pre-warmed instances.